# Activity Tracking on webpage in scalajs

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scala.js

I am trying to track user activities on a web page like if the user is on the current tab then it should return TRUE and then it should track the mouse activities like number of left clicks, number of right clicks, does the user scroll, maximum value of mouse up, mouse down, mouse left, mouse right, for much time the user was on the current tab and time period from the loading of page to the first click on the page etc. 
I am importing dom.document to refer to the web page and the code is :

```
import scala.scalajs.js.JSApp
import org.scalajs.dom
import dom.document

object test extends JSApp{

def main():Unit = {
  val title=document.title.toString() 
}

def appendPar(targetNode: dom.Node, text: String): Unit = {
val parNode = document.createElement("p")
val textNode = document.createTextNode(text)
parNode.appendChild(textNode)
targetNode.appendChild(parNode)
 }
}
```

I am building a scalajs project. How can I do the above task ? Please guide me from here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @sjrd I have tried to count the number of left and right mouse clicks. My code is like this :

    document.onclick={
        (e: dom.MouseEvent) =>
             i=i+1
            println("Mouse clicks are "+i)
      }

It is incrementing the number of mouse clicks (both left and right) on the page but first it is not calculating left and right separately and second, it should calculate the no. of clicks in a period of time like no. of clicks in every second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general operations with mouse events you can start from this:

```
dom.document.onmousedown = (e: dom.MouseEvent) => println("mouseup")
dom.document.onmouseup = (e: dom.MouseEvent) => println("mouseup")
dom.document.onmousemove = (e: dom.MouseEvent) => println("mousemove")
dom.document.onmouseout = (e: dom.MouseEvent) => println("mouseout")
dom.document.onmouseover = (e: dom.MouseEvent) => println("mouseout")
dom.document.onmousewheel = (e: dom.MouseEvent) => println("mousewheel")
```

If you need to count clicks in every period of time (for instance every second):

```
var count = 0 //your counter
var n = 0 //number of times

dom.document.onmousedown = (e: dom.MouseEvent) => count += 1


// ms - duration of an interval in ms

def countMousedown(ms: Int): Unit ={

  if (n == 100) return
  n += 1

  if(n != 0) println(count)

  count = 0

  dom.setTimeout(() => countMousedown(ms), ms)
}

countMousedown(1000)
```

To get coordinates:

```
dom.document.onmousedown = (e: dom.MouseEvent) => {

  val coords = (e.clientX, e.clientY)

  println(s"x: ${coords._1}, y: ${coords._2}")

}
```

Comment: What if I had to determine the mouse coordinates ? I've tried importing java.awt.MouseInfo class but it seems that it is not supported in scala.

Comment: @Ishan : java.awt.MouseInfo is not in the game in this case. Welcome to the Javascript world!

Comment: `dom.document.onmousedown = (e: dom.MouseEvent) => println(e.clientX)`

Comment: Yes, I am not familiar with JavaScript.

Comment: And I wanted to determine the coordinates only when the mouse is clicked.. So I did the following and it worked : 

`document.onclick = {
      (e: dom.MouseEvent) =>
        { x= e.pageX
            y =e.pageY
            println("Position is: ("+x+","+y+")")
          }
        }`

But thanks for pointing me to the right direction.